# In browser can I get the image color where my mouse is pointing at?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, color-picker

There is a web application for me to build, and rather than image map, I would like to try something more elegant.

The story is, there gonna be a global map where different continents are denoted by different colors.

Say Australia is red and Asia is green.

Will there be a way that when my mouse is hovering on the shape of Australia that my code will tell me that I am hovering on Australia by checking for the color where my cursor is currently pointing at?

I know I can check for mouse coordinates on image or something else, but I really want to get something that is not depending on pre-defined values/shapes/margins.

Any idea and suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Here are some other nice ideas for map highlighting (1) David Lynch's jQuery plugin (http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/maphilight-image-map-mouseover-highlighting/) and (2) Another Mapper (http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what kind of element your map is. It is definitely possible for certain elements in browsers that support `canvas`, but not for the whole page.

See the answers to my similar question: [**JavaScript eyedropper (tell colour of Pixel under mouse cursor)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936021/javascript-eyedropper-tell-colour-of-pixel-under-mouse-cursor)

Comment: thanks a lot for this quick answer, let me go and have a check!

Answer (score 2):

Merging various references found here in StackOverflow and in other sites, I did so using javascript and JQuery:

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'photo_apple.jpg';
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };

    function findPos(obj){
    var current_left = 0, current_top = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent){
        do{
            current_left += obj.offsetLeft;
            current_top += obj.offsetTop;
        }while(obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return {x: current_left, y: current_top};
    }
    return undefined;
    }

    function rgbToHex(r, g, b){
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
    }

$('#myCanvas').click(function(e){
    var position = findPos(this);
    var x = e.pageX - position.x;
    var y = e.pageY - position.y;
    var coordinate = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
    var canvas = this.getContext('2d');
    var p = canvas.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    var hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);
    alert("HEX: " + hex);
});
</script>
<img src="photo_apple.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I only used canvas and one image, but if you need to use `<map>` over the image, it's possible too.
I hope I have helped!