# Good JS lib to take screenshot of the screen

Tags: javascript, image, cross-browser, screenshot

I want my users to be able to take a screenshot of the webpage (or me defining the size of the screenshot) and then allowing them to save it to their computer.

Does anyone know of a good JS lib that allows you to do this?

I know there are addons for the browser, but i wanted something pure JS so that the user can just click in a button and a "save as" link apears with a screenshot of what they are looking at.

Thanks for the help.

/fmsf

Comment: Not possible, there is no cross-browser solution to create screenshots with pure javascript (assuming there's a pure javascript solution for any browser).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take in-browser screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers don't expose APIs that allow this to web pages, so there is no way to achieve this using plain JavaScript running in a page.

The only way to achieve this would be to have screen grabs prepared on the server, and a normal download link pointing to the appropriate one.

Comment: yeah we're already doing that, but it brings a great overload to our server, has making the screenshot means to render the page and load the object system. That's why i wanted to avoid it and make it happen on the client side

Comment: Maybe this used to be impossible, but it's not anymore. Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done in JavaScript. Taking screen shots outside the current document/domain is a potential security problem and is not possible. See my question about [getting the pixel colour from the current mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936021/javascript-eyedropper-tell-colour-of-pixel-under-mouse-cursor) for more background.

If you need to transmit the screen shots onto your server, look into external applications that interact with your web site. Open-source bug tracker [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/blog/?p=13) for example has a screenshot application for Windows.

If the screenshot and the saving of the file are both to take place on the client computer, check out [Fireshot](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/5648/) for Firefox. It doesn't seem to offer any interaction capabilities with a pre-defined web site but may be the right tool for your users.

Comment: +1. Mozilla have extended canvas with [`.drawWindow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas#section_9), but it's only available to code running with full privileges for the security reasons you mentioned in your post.  The [source code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/content/canvas/src/nsCanvasRenderingContext2D.cpp#2352) hints that these security issues may be worked around in the future, however.

Answer (score 1):

HTML2Canvas (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) recreates the rendered HTML into a canvas. And you can save the canvas as an image. That could do the trick, although it's not 100% accurate (and for good reasons - that would open security holes in browsers if that was possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1936084/1333479).