# how to see if a pixel's color is red? (with jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image and I want to see if the pixel that the mouse is on it is red or not to decide to do something in the following function, how can I find out that the pixel is red or not ?

```
$('#picture').mousemove(function(e) {} ;)
```

Comment: `if (pixel == 'red')`, seriously though, you can't do that without a canvas and some complicated math stuff.

Comment: Try this plugin http://www.project-sierra.de/ImageColorPicker/example/

Comment: this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735470/get-pixel-color-from-canvas-on-mouseover

Comment: reminds me of old days, programming in assembly :)

Comment: As an answer is already accepted, I'll add a quick demonstration here -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r8gtT/1/) !

Comment: @adeneo please write your answer as an answer so that people can see your complete answer and use it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with canvas. Draw the image on a canvas, after that using `getImageData` method you can get the image's pixels. As last step calculate the right pixel where the mouse is located and check it's red value (you'll have the RGBA for the pixel).

Probably the most tricky part will be to find the right pixel but this shouldn't be a big issue. Use the relative mouse position for the canvas. You'll already know how big is the image so it'll be easy to find the pixel.