# Generate a Color Using a Number Range and Gradient in Javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, gradient

I have numbers that range from 0 to 1, and depending on this number I want a color to be made that goes from red to orange to green (#FF0000 at 0, #FF9900 at .5, #00FF00 at 1). Colors in between would be made using a gradient(http://i.imgur.com/AD9avXh.png as an example of a possible gradient).

Does my question make sense? I'll answer any questions :D

Is this possible using JavaScript?

Thanks in advance!

SOLVED! Thanks again techfoobar <3

```
function componentToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}


function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}

function getColor(input) {
    if (input > 1 || input < 0)
        return "#00FFFF";
    var p = context.getImageData(input * 100, 0, 1, 1).data;
    var hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);
    return hex;
}

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.id = 'myCanvas';
canvas.width = 101;
canvas.height = 1;

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var grd = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

grd.addColorStop(0, '#FF0000');
grd.addColorStop(.5, '#FF9900');

grd.addColorStop(1, '#00FF00');
context.fillStyle = grd;
context.fill();
```

getColor() would be the method to use, works for values 0-1, anything greater than 1 or less than 0 returns cyan.
To change the range you would change the width of the canvas, adjust the first if in getColor, and change the grd.addColorStop() lines accordingly

Comment: Render a one pixel tall strip of your gradient image to a canvas. Depending on the value of the number, pick the appropriate pixel color from the canvas. For example, if the width of your canvas (with the gradient image strip) is 100 pixels, you should pick the color at 50, 0 when your number is 0.5.

Comment: This answer will helping in picking the color from the canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6736135/921204

Comment: And you can use this to draw your gradient image to the canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage()

Comment: Hmm, this makes sense when you say it but will be tricky for me to do, but I will try. Thank you!

Comment: How do i use this canvas but now actually draw it?

Comment: I've solved it! Infinite thanks to techfoobar <3

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
 throw "Invalid color component";
return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}
function getColor(input){
var p = context.getImageData(input*100, 0, 1, 1).data; 
var hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);
return hex;
}

Comment: var canvas=  document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.id='myCanvas';
canvas.width=101;
canvas.height=1;
      
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var grd = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

grd.addColorStop(0, '#FF0000');   
grd.addColorStop(.5, '#FF9900'); 
grd.addColorStop(1, '#00FF00');
context.fillStyle = grd;
context.fill();

Comment: Glad I could be of help.. :-) Have fun.