# Get pixel color from resized canvas, on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, getimagedata

I have checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735470/get-pixel-color-from-canvas-on-mouseover) which provides the perfect answer. But my problem is slightly different. I have a canvas of `300 x 300` and i am re-sizing the canvas using `css` to `200 x 60`. If i re-size the canvas using css i am not able to get the color value `onmouseover`.

In the re-sized fiddle if you mouse over right below the red or blue rectangles you will notice it still says `#FF0000` & `#0000FF` respectively while it should be `#000000`. So how to make it work even with re-sized canvas?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DV9Bw/1159/): Re-sized with css.**

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DV9Bw/1/): Non re-sized.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply a scale factor inside the mouse handler method. The scale factor is the relationship between your canvas's bitmap (actual size) and the element size (CSS size).

### For example:

```
// find scale:
var sx = example.width / parseInt(example.style.width, 10);
var sy = example.height / parseInt(example.style.height, 10);

// apply to x/y
x = (x * sx)|0;  // scale and cut any fraction to get integer value
y = (y * sy)|0;
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/DV9Bw/1160/)**

In addition the code need to have some boundary check of the coordinates so `getImageData()` won't fail (not shown here).