# Hover over data point on leaflet-heatmap.js heatmap to get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, leaflet, heatmap

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-leaflet.html) and have modified it to meet my needs (mapping Air Quality Index by zip-code). Now I want to hover over a data point to get its value.

Here is the code from the tutorial, which is fairly close to what I ended up with:

```
var testData = {
  max: 8,
  data: [{lat: 24.6408, lng:46.7728, count: 3},{lat: 50.75, lng:-1.55, count: 1},{lat: 52.6333, lng:1.75, count: 1},{lat: 48.15, lng:9.4667, count: 1},{lat: 52.35, lng:4.9167, count: 2},{lat: 60.8, lng:11.1, count: 1},{lat: 43.561, lng:-116.214, count: 1},{lat: 47.5036, lng:-94.685, count: 1},{lat: 42.1818, lng:-71.1962, count: 1},{lat: 42.0477, lng:-74.1227, count: 1},{lat: 40.0326, lng:-75.719, count: 1},{lat: 40.7128, lng:-73.2962, count: 2},{lat: 27.9003, lng:-82.3024, count: 1},{lat: 38.2085, lng:-85.6918, count: 1},{lat: 46.8159, lng:-100.706, count: 1},{lat: 30.5449, lng:-90.8083, count: 1},{lat: 44.735, lng:-89.61, count: 1},{lat: 41.4201, lng:-75.6485, count: 2},{lat: 39.4209, lng:-74.4977, count: 1},{lat: 39.7437, lng:-104.979, count: 1},{lat: 39.5593, lng:-105.006, count: 1},{lat: 45.2673, lng:-93.0196, count: 1},{lat: 41.1215, lng:-89.4635, count: 1},{lat: 43.4314, lng:-83.9784, count: 1},{lat: 43.7279, lng:-86.284, count: 1},{lat: 40.7168, lng:-73.9861, count: 1},{lat: 47.7294, lng:-116.757, count: 1},{lat: 47.7294, lng:-116.757, count: 2},{lat: 35.5498, lng:-118.917, count: 1},{lat: 34.1568, lng:-118.523, count: 1},{lat: 39.501, lng:-87.3919, count: 3},{lat: 33.5586, lng:-112.095, count: 1},{lat: 38.757, lng:-77.1487, count: 1},{lat: 33.223, lng:-117.107, count: 1},{lat: 30.2316, lng:-85.502, count: 1},{lat: 39.1703, lng:-75.5456, count: 8},{lat: 30.0041, lng:-95.2984, count: 2},{lat: 29.7755, lng:-95.4152, count: 1},{lat: 41.8014, lng:-87.6005, count: 1},{lat: 37.8754, lng:-121.687, count: 7},{lat: 38.4493, lng:-122.709, count: 1},{lat: 40.5494, lng:-89.6252, count: 1},{lat: 42.6105, lng:-71.2306, count: 1},{lat: 40.0973, lng:-85.671, count: 1},{lat: 40.3987, lng:-86.8642, count: 1},{lat: 40.4224, lng:-86.8031, count: 4},{lat: 47.2166, lng:-122.451, count: 1},{lat: 32.2369, lng:-110.956, count: 1},{lat: 41.3969, lng:-87.3274, count: 2},{lat: 41.7364, lng:-89.7043, count: 2},{lat: 42.3425, lng:-71.0677, count: 1},{lat: 33.8042, lng:-83.8893, count: 1},{lat: 36.6859, lng:-121.629, count: 2},{lat: 41.0957, lng:-80.5052, count: 1},{lat: 46.8841, lng:-123.995, count: 1},{lat: 40.2851, lng:-75.9523, count: 2},{lat: 42.4235, lng:-85.3992, count: 1},{lat: 39.7437, lng:-104.979, count: 2},{lat: 25.6586, lng:-80.3568, count: 7},{lat: 33.0975, lng:-80.1753, count: 1},{lat: 25.7615, lng:-80.2939, count: 1},{lat: 26.3739, lng:-80.1468, count: 1},{lat: 37.6454, lng:-84.8171, count: 1},{lat: 34.2321, lng:-77.8835, count: 1},{lat: 34.6774, lng:-82.928, count: 1},{lat: 39.9744, lng:-86.0779, count: 1},{lat: 35.6784, lng:-97.4944, count: 2},{lat: 33.5547, lng:-84.1872, count: 1},{lat: 27.2498, lng:-80.3797, count: 1},{lat: 41.4789, lng:-81.6473, count: 1},{lat: 41.813, lng:-87.7134, count: 1},{lat: 41.8917, lng:-87.9359, count: 1},{lat: 35.0911, lng:-89.651, count: 1},{lat: 32.6102, lng:-117.03, count: 1},{lat: 41.758, lng:-72.7444, count: 1},{lat: 39.8062, lng:-86.1407, count: 1},{lat: 41.872, lng:-88.1662, count: 1},{lat: 34.1404, lng:-81.3369, count: 1},{lat: 46.15, lng:-60.1667, count: 1},{lat: 36.0679, lng:-86.7194, count: 1},{lat: 43.45, lng:-80.5, count: 1},{lat: 44.3833, lng:-79.7, count: 1},{lat: 45.4167, lng:-75.7, count: 2},{lat: 43.75, lng:-79.2, count: 2},{lat: 45.2667, lng:-66.0667, count: 3},{lat: 42.9833, lng:-81.25, count: 2},{lat: 44.25, lng:-79.4667, count: 3},{lat: 45.2667, lng:-66.0667, count: 2},{lat: 34.3667, lng:-118.478, count: 3},{lat: 42.734, lng:-87.8211, count: 1},{lat: 39.9738, lng:-86.1765, count: 1},{lat: 33.7438, lng:-117.866, count: 1},{lat: 37.5741, lng:-122.321, count: 1},{lat: 42.2843, lng:-85.2293, count: 1},{lat: 34.6574, lng:-92.5295, count: 1},{lat: 41.4881, lng:-87.4424, count: 1},{lat: 25.72, lng:-80.2707, count: 1},{lat: 34.5873, lng:-118.245, count: 1},{lat: 35.8278, lng:-78.6421, count: 1}]
};

var baseLayer = L.tileLayer(
  'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
    attribution: '...',
    maxZoom: 18
  }
);

var cfg = {
  // radius should be small ONLY if scaleRadius is true (or small radius is intended)
  // if scaleRadius is false it will be the constant radius used in pixels
  "radius": 2,
  "maxOpacity": .8, 
  // scales the radius based on map zoom
  "scaleRadius": true, 
  // if set to false the heatmap uses the global maximum for colorization
  // if activated: uses the data maximum within the current map boundaries 
  //   (there will always be a red spot with useLocalExtremas true)
  "useLocalExtrema": true,
  // which field name in your data represents the latitude - default "lat"
  latField: 'lat',
  // which field name in your data represents the longitude - default "lng"
  lngField: 'lng',
  // which field name in your data represents the data value - default "value"
  valueField: 'count'
};


var heatmapLayer = new HeatmapOverlay(cfg);

var map = new L.Map('map-canvas', {
  center: new L.LatLng(25.6586, -80.3568),
  zoom: 4,
  layers: [baseLayer, heatmapLayer]
});

heatmapLayer.setData(testData);
```

Should I get the value by using Leaflet's bindPopup method or is there a better way of doing it? I'm using the latest version of Leaflet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I never really found the answer but I came up with a close alternative. Forgive me for the hackiness; it wasn't a huge project and I haven't had time to put more effort into it.

What I did was layer the map that I already had with Leaflet's bindPopup method, that way the user can click on the point to retrieve the data.

Here's my code for attaching the data to the click event:

```
for ( var i=0; i < airdata.length; ++i ) 
          {  
             if (airdata[i].AQI < 40) {
                 var circle = L.circle([airdata[i].LAT, airdata[i].LON], 1000, {
                      color: 'transparent',
                      fillColor: 'transparent', 
                      fillOpacity: airdata[i].AQI
                  })
                  .bindPopup(airdata[i].CITY + ', ' + airdata[i].STATE + '<br/>' + airdata[i].ZIPCODE + '<br/>' + 'AQI: ' + airdata[i].AQI.toString())
                  .addTo(map);
              } else if (airdata[i].AQI > 40 & airdata[i].AQI < 60) {
                  var circle = L.circle([airdata[i].LAT, airdata[i].LON], 1000, {
                      color: 'transparent',
                      fillColor: 'transparent',
                      fillOpacity: airdata[i].AQI
                  })
                  .bindPopup(airdata[i].CITY + ', ' + airdata[i].STATE + '<br/>' + airdata[i].ZIPCODE + '<br/>' + 'AQI: ' + airdata[i].AQI.toString())
                  .addTo(map);
              } else {
                  var circle = L.circle([airdata[i].LAT, airdata[i].LON], 1000, {
                      color: 'transparent',
                      fillColor: 'transparent',
                      fillOpacity: airdata[i].AQI
                  })
                  .bindPopup(airdata[i].CITY + ', ' + airdata[i].STATE + '<br/>' + airdata[i].ZIPCODE + '<br/>' + 'AQI: ' + airdata[i].AQI.toString())
                  .addTo(map);
              }
          }
          };
```

Not ideal, but if I had more time for this I would figure it out. Good luck!

Also, here's a helpful answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131944/leaflet-marker-mouseover-popup

Basically says to attach the data to leaflet's mouseover event.

Comment: Please take a moment to read [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) and in this case they should not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you will be able to do that with that specific heatmap plugin(http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/). It creates a Canvas overlay to deliver that heatmap effect. I suppose one thing you could do is sample the color of where your cursor is on the canvas then bring up a popup there. You can see a related answer for that here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23075007/1238737.

Comment: Any luck with that approach?

Comment: I have not had the time to resume this project. I'm hoping to jump back in tonight or tomorrow. I'll let you know what I end up doing. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Mawg! I never really figured out how to hover over the point to get the text, but I layered Leaflet's bindPopup on top of it to allow clicking the point to retrieve the text. See my edit for the code.

Answer (score 0):

this solution might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368547

```
var heatPane = map.getPanes('heatPane').overlayPane; // access the canvas
// now, use mousemove on pane; the leaflet map.on("mousemove", function (e){}) won't help
heatPane.onmousemove = function (e) { 
var display_val = lyrHEAT._heatmap.getValueAt({
    x: e.layerX,
    y: e.layerY
});
 // display wherever you like the 'display_val' parameter, either as tooltip or in a div
};
```