# How to get the pixel color from a canvas on click of mouse event with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, require

I have a picture in canvas, and the goal is to get the code RGB color while clicking in a pixel.

Comment: You can see this answer(the same issue):
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6736135/5192642