# check cell color in table in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I built a 10*10 table using canvas. Each cell is randomly colored green, blue or red. Now I want to check every cell in the table for its color and change it if it's the same as its neighbor. 
How do I check the color of each cell?

```js
var color;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
function drawBoard() {

    for (let i = 0; i < 440; i += 40) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(i, 0);
        context.lineTo(i, 400);
        context.stroke();

    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 440; i += 40) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, i);
        context.lineTo(400, i);
        context.stroke();

    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 440; i += 40) {//row
        for (let j = 0; j < 440; j += 40) {//column
            let color = randomColor();
            context.fillStyle = color;
            context.fillRect(j , i , 40, 40);
        }
    }


}

drawBoard();

function randomColor() {
    let colorOptions = ["RED", "BLUE", "GREEN"];
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorOptions.length);
    return colorOptions[index];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
     
    <canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="600"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, any idea. But first, tell us your ideas? Did you try anything?

Comment: I want to use document.getElementById but not sure how execlly becouse I new at javascript. I've already built the board in CANVAS and randomly colored all the cells,but do not know now how to check a cell cell because it is not a two-dimensional array like in JAVA for example

Comment: It's really simple to search SO or the web and for example find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735470/get-pixel-color-from-canvas-on-mouseove

Comment: using document.getElementById for 100 cells is certainly possible, but it would be cleaner to give them a class name like "cell" and use document.getElementsByClassName("cell"). Now you get a node list that you can loop over to check each items style.background

Comment: I added my code, but how I added class name to every cell?

Comment: You aren't using DOM elements so in this case you wouldn't. In your example you will use the simpler approach of using javascript. I provided an answer that solves what you are trying to do, but the code would be far better if rewritten with the end goal in mind.

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory consider accepting it, or explain why it's not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Update after code was provided

With your code you are setting a color and then drawing it without storing that information. My recommendation would be to restructure your code so that each cell is an object with values if you want to manipulate them afterwards. If you want a quick fix I would index random colors to each cell. One more option would be to get the color value from a pixel in each cell. Example provided in this post: [Get pixel color from canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735470/get-pixel-color-from-canvas-on-mouseover)

Normally when you make a for loop you will increase the count by 1. Your code would be easier to work with if you looped from 0 to 9 instead of 0 to 440. But using what you provided you could create an array like the snippet below.

What I do here is create an array containing the 121 (11 by 11) colors. Then when drawing we use an index in the array for each drawing. To modify colors all you have to do is manipulate the array.

As per your original post, you want no squares to be equal to its neighbor. I added this into the setup of the array instead of checking afterwards.

```
while(arr[i] === arr[i -1] || arr[i] === arr[i -10]) {
arr[i] = randomColor();
}
```

this makes sure no color is pushed to the array if the color left of itself or top of itself. This code is slow since it can run the randomColor() function many times for every cell.

### Original Answer

There are many ways to do what you described. Depending on how you created your table the answer will vary. Some possibilities:

- Each cell could be a javascript object with a `color:` property.
- When creating the random setup just push the colors to an array and fetch each cells color to that of its index in the array.
- There is a way to draw DOM objects on canvas, if this is your approach you could check the objects style property. Likely `yourCell.style.background`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const colorArray = fillArray();

function drawBoard() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 440; i += 40) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(i, 0);
        context.lineTo(i, 400);
        context.stroke();

    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 440; i += 40) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, i);
        context.lineTo(400, i);
        context.stroke();

    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 440; i += 40) {//row
        for (let j = 0; j < 440; j += 40) {//column
            context.fillStyle = colorArray[i/4 + j/40];
            context.fillRect(j , i , 40, 40);
        }
    }

}

drawBoard();

function fillArray() {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 121; i += 1) {
    arr.push(randomColor());
    while(arr[i] === arr[i -1] || arr[i] === arr[i -10]) {
    arr[i] = randomColor();
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
function randomColor() {
    let colorOptions = ["RED", "BLUE", "GREEN"];
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorOptions.length);
    return colorOptions[index];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
     
    <canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="600"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I added my code... not sure I understand you how to use yourCell.style.background