# How to check if a color exists in an image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, colors, textures

I have a very simple set of images, where each image is white plus one color. Well, not quite...

This "one color" is actually a single hex color overlayed on a terrain sort of texture, so it gets all sorts of highs and lows in terms of shadows and lightness as it is overlaid on the terrain. So how can we detect if this color is present in an image? Say we have a set of the 7 rainbow colors and each one only belongs to one image.

I have 7 images in the DOM, each with a different color. What is the easiest way to select the DOM selector for the image which has a certain color? Seems like an advanced canvas thing but I'm not sure where to start.

Basically, how to select the "red" image out of the set of rainbow images, and the "blue" image. Given that you know precisely what the "main" red hex value is that you used to create the red *texture*, etc. Now your red texture might not have any of the red from the original hex values, but it seems like it will (at least from a visual perspective) have a range of colors which are "close" to that red... whatever that means.

So wondering how we can detect if our hex value was used to generate the terrain, I guess is another way of framing it. Given that we know nothing about the underlying terrain other than what the final composited image is.

Comment: You could get the ctx and loop `getImageData()` to find the colour. However, since you output the image somehow, why not just add a data-attribute for those colours? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735470/get-pixel-color-from-canvas-on-mouseover

Comment: That question is way too broad for SO and is (imho) literally just asking "do my job for me". Grab the images, add them onto a canvas, check the colors (hsl/hsv or just plain rgb) -> success.