# How can I access the values given by gpu.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, gpu.js

I am learning to use `gpu.js` to do calculations in the GPU. I am able to do my calculations for  two JavaScript matrices `a` and `b` and to display the result as a canvas image.

**Question: How can I access the calculated numerical values?** The values are generated by

```
const render = gpu.createKernel(function(a,b) {
        this.color(
    Math.sqrt(-2*Math.log(a[this.thread.y][this.thread.x]))*Math.cos(2*3.14*b[this.thread.y][this.thread.x]), 
    Math.sqrt(-2*Math.log(a[this.thread.y][this.thread.x]))*Math.sin(2*3.14*b[this.thread.y][this.thread.x]),
     0, 1);
}).setOutput([512, 512]).setGraphical(true);
```

Perhaps there is another setting instead of `.setGraphical(true)` which creates a standard JavaScript array, which I can then access.

Or perhaps (I don't think this is the right way) I should access the values of the canvas with some code like

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var p = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
```

as in [Get pixel color from canvas, on mousemove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735470/get-pixel-color-from-canvas-on-mousemove)

My code is at http://integraali.com/jsxgraph/kuvat/turbojs/kuvasta4.html
(I tried to put my code to JSFiddle, but the code did not work there. Perhaps JSFiddle does not allow to load `gpu.js`, I don't know what is the issue.)

Answer (score 1):

After 3 hours, I found the answer from here: https://gist.github.com/globalpolicy/bb74dbbe7500b9d51da00b4797c7064d

Works in my website: http://integraali.com/jsxgraph/kuvat/gpujs/index.html