# Clicking on transparent image

Tags: javascript, image, click, png, transparency

I have an square image depicting a car on a transparent background. I want to be able to click on car, yet when I click on it's transparent background I'd like the click to go through the image and trigger on the underlying DOM element (or, specifically, other image).

Can that be achieved somehow?

Comment: Only with a [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/map) attached to the image.

Comment: @lanzz, nice thought, please post it as an answer, so the OP (and others) may benefit from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite complex, but can be achieved by combining **Pointer events** to allow for the `click` to bubble up the DOM (reaching the `img` parent container), and a faux **Canvas** on top to detect a transparent pixel (which will be used as a flag to activate the event delegation).

Pointer events were derived from the SVG model to allow for event delegation across layers. Note that they're currently [not supported on IE and Opera](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events).

**Related Posts:**

- [A technique used for pixel color detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936021/javascript-eyedropper-tell-color-of-pixel-under-mouse-cursor)
- [Get pixel from an HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas)

**Demo:**

- [`pointer-events` on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/JwUqw/)

**Reference:**

- [`pointer-events` on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events/)
- [Pixel based manipulation on Dev.Opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/#pixelbasedmanipulation)

**Further Read:**

- [An article on the subject by Robert Nyman](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/22/css-pointer-events-to-allow-clicks-on-underlying-elements/)
- [John Resig on transforming image data](http://ejohn.org/blog/ocr-and-neural-nets-in-javascript/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Eliran. Will be doing further research.

Answer (score 0):

No, click events on images are not controlled by the transparency of the image. The click will always be triggered on the image, then bubble up to the parent if it's not stopped.

An image can have semi transparent pixels, and if a pixel has for example 61% opacity, then 37% of the click would go to the parent element, and that is of course not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw nan SVG shape around the car and put the picture inside it, then listen for click events on the shape.