# Searching after color picker jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, colors, picker

I'm searching after a color picker jquery plugin, but not like all this: 
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-color-pickers-plugin/#.UHK6XU1mKa8

I want to have a tool like in Photoshop when you can take sample of the color of any pixel in the image.

I'm looking for such tool in jquery for html + css page.

Anyone know something like this?

Thanks

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936021/javascript-eyedropper-tell-color-of-pixel-under-mouse-cursor.

Comment: This is talking about how to take sample of image pixel. I'm looking for tool to take sample from any element that I have on my html page. live text, background, multiple images.

Comment: Please, check the updated version of my answer. It seems it does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is not that difficult as it might seem to be. Even you can implement it by yourself. For that you should use the `<canvas>` element (it has a possibility to pick up a pixel data).

First, you can take the screenshot of HTML content and transfer it to the `<canvas>`. In order to do that, you may use **[html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)** library.

Then, you should use the `<canvas>` data to pick up the color. Here is the short solution for that:

```
var img = new Image(),
    cbox = $("div"),
    canvas = $("canvas"),
    context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

img.src = "/img/logo.png";
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

canvas.on("mousemove", function(e) {
    var data = context.getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data,
        arr = $.makeArray(data);

    cbox.css("background-color", "rgba(" + arr.join(",") + ")");
});
```

**​DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Fd3pZ/

However, you should consider that the provided solution will work only in browsers which support `<canvas>` and `rgba()` as CSS color mode (`rgb()` can be used instead though).

---

And here is the complete solution after embedding **html2canvas** library.

```
$("body").on("mousemove", "canvas", function(e) {
    var data = this.getContext("2d").getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data,
        arr = $.makeArray(data);

    $("#color").css("background-color", "rgba(" + arr.join(",") + ")");
});

$("#content").html2canvas();​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Fd3pZ/1/

Comment: The html2canvas script is the best for this mission? Because I saw in his examples some inaccuracies by rendering. Like here: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/tests/borders.html