# Jquery Color Picker which supports eye dropper

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I am looking for a color picker in jQuery which also supports eye dropper functionality.

Comment: I have googled it a lot, but not able to find one single plugin which supports both, other than http://www.dematte.at/colorPicker/#top, which i don't find that useful

Comment: check this out http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-color-pickers-plugin/

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, i have checked this already, which one of these you think supports both

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936021/javascript-eyedropper-tell-color-of-pixel-under-mouse-cursor

Comment: This question is off-topic; [questions asking only for recommendations of libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic for Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251134/2747593). See also the [Help/On-Topic].

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you need  https://github.com/sstrudeau/jquery-dropper

Comment: Please use the comment section

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post answers on obviously off topic / bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) In addition, please don't post [answers that consist solely or primarily of a link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503). Instead, add some context around the link so that your answer is still valid even if e.g. the site you linked to goes down.