# Dynamically change color of following-mouse-div, complementary to the color underneath it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div that follows the mouse pointer and I would like that div to change its color with a complementary color, according to the color underneath it. 
So it needs to measure the color of whatever is undernith the mouse at any point and assign the complementary color to the div that follows the mouse pointer.
Something like Gpick is doing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oy7_PadJ1Ig

Comment: please show the things you've done so far.

Comment: @Pekka I'm trying to learn these things, but until now I could only make the div follow the mouse pointer and position it under the mouse pointer. `jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e){
        var px =e.pageX-122;
        var py =e.pageY-70;
        jQuery(".nav-trigger-fl").css({left:px+ "px", top:py+"px"});
    });`

Answer (score 0):

I have created demo example you can check here

```
$("div").mousemove(function(e){
  $('.follow').css({'top': e.clientY - 20, 'left': e.clientX - 20});
});
$("div").mouseover(function() {
   var col=$(this).css("background-color");
   $("#myid").css("background-color",col);

});
```

[Click on this to see Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vijayktpr1/Lt2wH/412/)

Comment: Thanks, it's a good start, but I think I need something more complicated. I found something related, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936021/javascript-eyedropper-tell-color-of-pixel-under-mouse-cursor