# How to get color of pixel on screen on mousemove?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Just want to get pixel color on mouse move in jquery or javascript. Is there any possible way to get that as I don't want to use canvas or any third party plugin. I need color of that pixel on my cursor position.

Any one please help?

Comment: As I want to get that background area on my current mouse's position. Is it possible with any way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936021/javascript-eyedropper-tell-color-of-pixel-under-mouse-cursor
Is this your question? If yes check there

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is background color you can use `document.elementFromPoint()` and `getComputedStyle()`.

For more advanced issues like pixel color in an image this will not work

```js
window.addEventListener('click', e=>{
  const {clientX:x, clientY:y} = e,
      el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y),
      style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
      
  console.log(style.backgroundColor)
});

initDemo()

function initDemo(){
  const colors =['red','blue', 'purple','green','grey']

  document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach((el,i)=>{
   el.style.backgroundColor = colors[i]
  });
}
```

```css
.box{ border:2px solid #ccc; width:50px; margin:30px; height:50px; display:inline-block; color:yellow}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: There are random html on my screen, I want pixel color on mouse move.

Comment: Not possible with just html. See link above. You made comment that all you want is background or I wouldn't have even provided this answer