# How to create color picker with extra functionality like choosing color from screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, colors, legend, color-picker

I have an colorpicker which i created using react-color (https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/) . Now I want extra functionality like it should also be able to choose the color from screen (toggle color picker).
I found few available library but it looks like it works only through inspect element but not sure if I am right.

**What I want:**

[image]

What I currently have (done using react-color library)

[image]

Can anybody guide me like how I can add extra functionality of choosing color from screen to this existing color picker (which is done using react-color library) .

Comment: When you say "on the screen" - do you only need [color of DOM elements on the current web page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67458422/12418176)? Or do you need [more complex objects but still within your own current web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936021/javascript-eyedropper-tell-color-of-pixel-under-mouse-cursor)? Or something else like you want to be able to get the color of anything on your current screen as in within other applications running on your computer?

Comment: I want something like eyedropper that the pointer should be able to pick the color from the current webpage and should not be too complex at least for now. My current functionality only picks color from color picker and not from screen.

Comment: Does the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67458422/12418176) from my previous comment solve your use-case then?

Comment: Unfortunately no because it only pick color from the box and not the screen. I want something like https://jsfiddle.net/o4nsxhpz/ , if you click the input box here , you can see pen icon and from that u can choose color from screen but I cannot use this input code since I already have picker and I need only the functionality of that pen icon. I am using this color picker in my app (https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/) and it only missing the functionality provided by that pen icon in the fiddle link.

Comment: it picks the background color of whatever you click on screen. the boxes are only there as examples for different colors to try to pick. for example, if you click anywhere other than the boxes, it logs `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` for the white background. the code does it by attaching onto clicks on the webpage, grabbing the element where your mouse was when you clicked and then logging what the background color of that element is. Sounds exactly what you're looking for - you just hook it up into an icon which enables this mode and then do something other than console.log the color.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `<input type="color" />`?

```html
<input type="color" />
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the only functionality which the pencil icon is doing in your example like picking from screen since I already have picker using react-color which I cannot replace with <input type="color" /> unfortunately.

Comment: I am using this color picker in my app (casesandberg.github.io/react-color) and it only missing the functionality provided by that pen icon (<input type="color" />) .

Comment: No the you can't do that with <input type="color" />, there is a library called react-eyedrop that allows you to get colors from an image. here's a code sand box [Code sandbox react-eyedrop][https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-cloud-vpcnoy?file=/src/App.js] is this what you want?

Comment: Not sure why I am not able to run and see the code sandbox (codesandbox.io/s/strange-cloud-vpcnoy?file=/src/App.js), not able to see the output

Comment: Now try to copy-paste a hex colour into the default input modal in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the **EyeDropper API**.
At the moment (2023) It's only supported by Chromium browsers (Chrome, Edge, Opera).
In regards to other browsers, here's the "Request for position" issues for:

- [Firefox](https://github.com/mozilla/standards-positions/issues/557)
- [Safari](https://github.com/WebKit/standards-positions/issues/29)

At the moment both are open (they haven't decided anything yet).

---

### Example implementation

(obviously this only works in supported browsers)

```js
async function sampleColor() {
  if('EyeDropper' in window) {
    const ed = new EyeDropper();
    const color = await ed.open();
    if(color) {
      setColorSwatch(color.sRGBHex)
    }
  }
}

function setColorSwatch(rgb) {
  document.getElementById('swatch').style.backgroundColor = rgb;
}
```

```css
#swatch {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sampleColor()">Pippette icon</button>

<div id="swatch"></div>
```