# How does colorZilla manage to pick color on webpages?

Tags: javascript, colors, color-picker

I'd like to know how colorZilla(the browser extension) does to get the color of every pixel
within web pages. It even succeeded to get the color of a character within a **TEXT_NODE**.

[image: Colorzilla picking the color of a character within the purple link a the bottom of the page]

How does it know that the mouse pointer is hovering a **TEXT_NODE** with an **ELEMENT_NODE**?

I already tried the browser EyeDropper API but it doesn't work and always returns `RGB(0,0,0)`. Maybe because it's still an [experimental technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EyeDropper).

PS: I don't think colorZilla uses the EyeDropper API anyway.

Here are links to the extension for those who don't know it:

- [Firefox ColorZilla extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colorzilla/)
- [Chrome ColorZilla extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorzilla/bhlhnicpbhignbdhedgjhgdocnmhomnp?hl=en)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript eyedropper (tell color of pixel under mouse cursor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936021/javascript-eyedropper-tell-color-of-pixel-under-mouse-cursor)

Comment: No, It doesn't. I updated my question to say why.

Comment: At least for Chrome they seem to call `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ColorZilla has 2 pieces of code working together, *ContentScript* and *BackgroundScript*.

*ContentScript* has access to current page's DOM context. It can add event listeners, can create DOM element (the toolbar UI), and it can also talk to the *BackgroundScript* via message passing using `Port.postMessage` API.

*BackgroundScript*, on the other hand doesn't have access to page's DOM, but it can use special privileged API provided by Chrome for extensions. `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` is the key here.

Upon color picking request, the *BackgroundScript* just captures the current page as image, and send the raw image data back to *ContentScript* via `postMessage`. Then *ContentScript* inject `mousemove` event listeners to the page, thus has your cursor position. Combining these 2 pieces of information, et voilà, now you can pick color at high precision.

---

If you're interested in finding out more details, go to this directory and look for 2 files:

```
# Extensions folder on macOS (don't know about Windows, sorry)
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/bhlhnicpbhignbdhedgjhgdocnmhomnp/2.0_0/js/

- content-script-combo.js  # ContentScript
- background.js            # BackgroundScript
```

Use prettier to format the code a bit, then search for keyword `"take-screenshot"`, it should take you to the relevant part of code. From there on, have fun digging!